# Networking or Wifi goes down randomly what could be the problem?

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager, xubuntu

WiFi disconnects from my rooter's AP and when I try to reconnect I get this error "(2) Active connection removed before it was initialized" it works again normally after I reboot, what could be the problem? 
I am running I3 on Xubuntu.

Comment: Could be related with DHCP. If possible, try using static IP address and check whether the error appears or not.

Comment: I already am using a static IP address and I still get that problem.

Comment: Until you find the solution, you could try to restart the Network Manager instead of rebooting. Execute `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`.